# memcmp to compare segments of an array (remove duplicates)

Tags: c, qsort, memcmp

I've been working on this for a while (in C) and can't figure it out.  I have a buffer containing an array of chars.  I've used qsort to sort through the array and it's all in proper order now.  I now need to remove duplicates (or just print out the list without duplicates).
There's a caveat: the chars are grouped into groups of N chars (the N given by the user).  So it's not just comparing one char next to the other; it's comparing groups of them against each other.

So for example: if the input is AADDBBEECCEE and the N given by the user is 2, the result would be AABBCCDDEE (with one of the EE's removed).

I know I have to use memcmp, but I'm confused about the syntax.  I'm trying:

```
i=0;
int result;
int k;
while(i<bufferSize-nValue){
    result = memcmp(buffer[i], buffer[i+nValue], nValue);
    if(result==0){
       i=i+nValue;
    }
    else{
       for(k=0; k<nValue; k++){
          printf("%c",buffer[i]);
          i++;
        }
     }
 }
```

where buffer is the array, nValue is  N, bufferSize is total number of elements in array.
I keep getting segmentation fault when running the code.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

```
memcmp(buffer[i], buffer[i+nValue], nValue);
```

`memcmp()` takes pointers. You probably mean `buffer+i` and `buffer+i+nValue` for the arguments. If that's the answer, I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn about that. Did you activate warnings?

Comment: IT WORKED.  thank you so much!!  No, my compiler (gcc) didn't warn me about that